# Jasmine test case in maven with requirejs

Tags: javascript, maven, requirejs, jasmine

I want to use jasmine for unit testing javascript application. My application uses requirejs. I found [Jasmine maven plugin](http://searls.github.io/jasmine-maven-plugin/)

This plugin works great for non requirejs application. It also has requirejs template but i am unable to successfully run testcases with maven.

I have written sample test case as

```js
require(['models/MyModel'], function(GlobalSettingsModel) {
  //this code doesn't execute
  describe('Test description', function() {
    it('some test', function(done) {
      expect(1 + 2).toBe(4); //it doesn't throw error
    });

  });
});

describe('Test description new', function() {

  require(['models/MyModel'], function(GlobalSettingsModel) {
    it('some test', function(done) {
      expect(1 + 2).toBe(4); //it doesn't throw error

    });
  });

});

describe('Test description new', function() {
  it('some test', function(done) {
    expect(1 + 2).toBe(4); //it throw error

  });

});
```

If i wrap my testcase inside requirejs then maven won't execute code inside requirejs block. If i give non existent js file in requirejs(first line) then it throw error that file is not exist.

I have tried many ways to integrate jasmine(requirejs) with maven but unable to find any other plugin or any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of wrapping describe method in require block, i need to wrap describe in define block

```js
define(['model'],
  function(Model) {
    describe('Test description new', function() {
      it('some test', function(done) {
        expect(1 + 2).toBe(4); //it throw error

      });

    });
  });
```